# Azure Blob Storage using only the file name, not the entire path

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

This works exactly as it should. It uses the entire file path to save the blobs in Azure. However, I would like only the file names to be saved directly into the "container" (not the entire hierarchical structure). Is there a good way to do this?

```
        string[] returnedPaths = Open_File_Dialog();

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // container
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_jobID);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        foreach (var filePath in returnedPaths)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);
            blob.UploadFromFile(filePath);
        }
```

Comment: How about just passing the filename portion of the path, to `GetBlockBlobReference()`? There shouldn't be any need to pass the entire path.

Comment: Thanks David. That worked. I'm was not familiar with how it worked. I thought GetBlockBlobReference() was the path to the original file.

Answer (score 2):

This was all that was needed.

```
foreach (var filePath in returnedPaths)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

                blob.UploadFromFile(filePath);
            }
```